# How can I reference existing groups in my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

I have already grouped cells in a spreadsheet using DATA>GROUP.

Based on a menu style system, I want to collapse/uncollapse a series of already created groups in a sheet, so that it only shows the selection chosen via the menu choices. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have a look at the [Range.ShowDetail Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.showdetail) and [Outline.ShowLevels Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.outline.showlevels).

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that.